# how to set a node to anonymous author?

Tags: nodes, users

Change node author works :

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node->set('uid','45');
$node->save();
```

But i don't know how to set it to anonymous user ? or unset it ?

```
 $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
 // set uid to anonymous ?
 $node->save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$node->set('uid', 0); $node->save` should have worked. Maybe you forgot to flush caches.

To programmatically set the author to anonymous user on any entity you can call `$entitiy->setOwnerId(0);` and then `$entity->save();`, done.

```php
$entity->setOwnerId(0);
$entity->save();
```

Comment: i figured out $node->set('uid', 0); $node->save worked indeed but the content was not listed on /admin/content because of the view relation with author. When opting out "Exiger cette relation" ,the content is there but the user column is empty instead of anonymous

Comment: both options work then but the content author is not set to anonymous as it is when deleting content and reassiging using the backoffice. The consequence is the /admin/content view must be modified in order to see the reassigned content with ownerId 0